# Apollo client can't query in Nextjs getServerSideProps via SchemaLink

Tags: next.js, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

Apollo client fails to do query when initialized with SchemaLink (nexus) instead of HttpLink. I get this error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'select')`

```js
function createIsomorphLink() {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    const { SchemaLink } = require('@apollo/client/link/schema')
    const { schema } = require('./nexusSchema')
    return new SchemaLink({ schema })
  } else {
    const { HttpLink } = require('@apollo/client/link/http')
    return new HttpLink({
      uri: '/api/graphql',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    })
  }
}

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: from([errorLink, createIsomorphLink()]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })
}
```

Here's my `getServerSideProps`. I initialize apollo client and use `apolloClient.query(...)`

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const id = params.id
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo()

  // Here's where the error occurs
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: gql`
      query findUniquePage($id: String!) {
        findUniquePage(where: { id: $id }) {
          title
          type
          content
          isPublished
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: { id },
  })

  // ...snippet..
}
```

I tried creating simple 'hello' query with string response, so that there was no select part. But error stayed the same.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo()

  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: gql`query hello { hello }`,
  })

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}
```

My apollo client version is 3.7.0. The latest is 3.7.1 but by [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/releases/tag/v3.7.1) there seems to be nothing that addresses my issue. Probably, the problem is how apollo client requests my api via SchemaLink, or how my api parses that request (apollo server + code first nexus). Because when I replaced SchemaLink with HttpLink, code worked fine. But I kinda want to keep the SchemaLink. Any advice?

Comment: My project was working, and after I upgraded some dependencies I have the same issue. In DEV mode, with Next.JS, "require" returns a promise. It used to return the schema synchronously.
See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37520
I do not have a solution yet. Interesting point is that the issue only show when I run "next dev". When I build and use "next start" it's fine...

Comment: So, I found a solution here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42931

Setting "experimental: { esmExternals: false }" in my next.config.js solves the issue.

However I think the entire Apollo client setup approach should be reworked instead.